# SELECCIONAR DATOS DE UNA TABLA CON SELENIUM

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

Hola por favor me gustaría saber como puedo encontrar la cantidad filas de una tabla y los valores de cada columna, el modelo de mi tabla es la siguiente, es una tabla algo compleja, por favor si alguien me puede ayudar para escribirle a un correo y darle mas datos

Comment: Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Cantidad de filas de una tabla de datos en Excel
Si la Hoja está vacía, da error de desbordamiento (se podría evitar)
Cuenta también parcialmente vacías en columna A1, hasta la última con datos
acaba situando el cursor en el última línea

```
Sub cuentafilas()
Dim nfilas As Integer
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
nfilas = ActiveCell.Row
MsgBox "En la Hoja Activa, " & ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name & " tengo " & nfilas & " filas", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Lo de los valores de cada columna? en ese caso el resultado es toda la tabla. Deberás concretar más el ejemplo y lo que quieres conseguir.

Un Saludo